# Is it possible to add any 'specific column' index to a SQL Server table created with "CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE" option?

Tags: sql-server, azure, columnstore

I have a table in an Azure SQL Server that was created using a `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE` index.

Shall I add any additional specific column(s) index on this table or is the table already optimized for read/write by the `COLUMNSTORE` itself?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Product
GO

CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    ProductID int,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Quantity int,
    INDEX cci CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/in-memory-oltp-overview#benefits-of-in-memory-technology), we can see Clustered columnstore indexes is one of the in-memory technologies and it can reduce our storage footprint (up to 10 times) and improve performance for reporting and analytics queries. So that it will increase performance without increasing our service tier.
2. As we know rowstore indexes perform best on queries that seek into the data, when searching for a particular value, or for queries on a small range of values.
   According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#what-is-a-columnstore-index), we can combine rowstore and columnstore on the same table in Azure sql.

**In summary:**
So you can add any `specific column` index , if it is necessary.